# Add a result from class object to another class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everyone I am new to Python and currently, I am learning about class.

I have two classes. 1 class has a result of the student's name and address.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, address, units = []):
        self.name=name
        self.addrress = address
        self.units=units
```

Now I have another class which is School. The class can store the Students by adding from Student class, count how many students are on the list, also delete the student data.

```
class School:
    def __init__(self):
        self.school = []
        
    def __len__(self):
        length(self.school)
        
    def admission(self, student):
        self.school.append(student)
    
    def delete_student(self, name, address):
        self.name=name
        self.organisation=organisation
        for i in range(0,len(self.school)):
            if self.name.lower() == name.lower() and self.address.lower() == address.lower():
                del self.school[i]
            else:
                print("The student you input is not exist")
```

I want to put all the students that I define from class Student into school.
When I do something like this

```
a = Student("Batman", "Gotham", ["Science","Chemi"])
b = Student("Harry", "Hogwarts", ["Magic"])

School.admission(a)
```

There are error that said admission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'student'

How to figure this out? Maybe I did wrong in calling the argument. Help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

=================================================

Comment: you are missing the `()` in `School.admission(a)` it must be `School().admission(a)`

Comment:  Technically yes, but that in itself would be rather useless code. You need to *instantiate* the school as well before admitting students to it: `s = School(); s.admission(a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`School` is the class, but you defined `admission` as an instance method. So you need an instance of `School` that you can admit students to:

```
school = School()
school.admission(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `admission` is an instance method, so you should define your school instance, then add students:

```
school1 = School()
school1.admission(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

people are saying that -

```
school1 = School()
school1.admission(a)
```

this resolves issue.
But try calling the list school from school1 and it will contain the student as class object like this

```
print(school1.school)
#output-
[<__main__.Student object at xyz...>]
```

So you should change your code like this...

```
def admission(self,student):
    self.school.append(student.name)
```

after changing this part of your code as how i metioned above let's try calling list now.

```
a=Student('harry','hogwarts',['magic','spells'])
school1=School()
school1.admission(a)
print(school1.school)
#output-
['harry']
```

sorry for bad variable names.
please upvote.